# Calling function in echo in for loop

Tags: bash, unix, ksh

My question is because this for continues cycling, and i don´t know how to stop the function but I have to use both functions.

```
for i in $var; do
  Stateful()
  {
    echo "-s $Statefuljunc";
    exit 1
  }

  if [[ "$Statefuljunc" == "yes" ]]; then
    echo "server task $i create -f -h $HOST -p $PORT -t $lower -c $idtypes \
      `$(RemoteAddress)` `$(Stateful)`  ";
  fi
done
```

Comment: Using both backticks and `$()` looks like a typo.

Comment: Move the Stateful() function above the for loop, remove the backtics, change $(RemoteAddress) into ${RemoteAddress} and try again. Edit your question with your results, including the value of ${var} and ${Statefuljunc}.
Statefuljunc is not changed inside the loop, so when it is "yes" for the first word in $var, it will try to call the function and exit, ignoring the other valurs in $var. When Statefuljunc is something else, the loop will finish without one echo.

Comment: You never change the value of `Statefuljunc`.

Comment: The functions need to be inside the loop, my question is how can I call the function result without the result keep looping, like an stop or wait, for printing only the result of the function return and when I call the other function do the same. I have to put the function outside the loop for do that?. Thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: I cannot put the function outside the loop because the value of Statefuljunc keep values are give with the loop. Just like this: `AuthenticationHTTP()
                {
                        if [[ -z $AuthenticationHTTP ]]; then
                                echo "-e $AuthenticationHTTP";
                        fi
                        exit 1
                }`